# Trouble installing on Lenovo N22 80S6

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, lenovo

On Lenovo N22 80S6 Ubuntu doesn't show on the boot menu after I "successfully installed" it. Here is the step-by-step of what I did:

(1)Downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.1 ISO, used YUMI to burn it to my 1TB seagate portable drive.

(2)Changed boot mode to Legacy Support and boot priority to Legacy First because I read that somewhere.

(3) Installed Ubuntu without trying live because on live, the installer got stuck on downloading package.

(4) I did not select "something else" but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2XG3.jpg) is what that screen looks like. I'm only showing this because I feel like something's not right there.

(5) Then I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7XRz.jpg) message.

(6) After 10-15 min the installation was supposedly finished.

(7) Unplugged the USB and computer shut off. When I turned it on I got a boot menu with 2 choices: eMMC Disk Samsung 64GB and Windows Boot Manager. Hitting enter on either of those choices just brought me back to the boot menu. I no longer have Windows (that was my decision but now I wish I had saved it so I can give up on Ubuntu).

Comment: windows is not there because you deleted the disk and made new partitions with only ubuntu. if installation was correct, then you shouldn't see windows in the bootloader. reinstall and this time take photos step by step. also we need to see that legacy option and that legacy 1st.

Comment: I tried to link all the photos but this forum only allowed 2 links in my question.               [Boot priority](http://imgur.com/a/QsSBr)       [Ubuntu install](http://imgur.com/a/dFRp8)      [Erase disk and install Ubuntu](http://imgur.com/a/1IMmV)            [Install complete](http://imgur.com/a/Akl3y)         [Boot menu after install](http://imgur.com/a/B7p9R)

Comment: Run the `boot-info` script, this may useful investigating your problem further. You can also try this answer from the live media: http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/40581 Save the error messages that may be generated.  I assume eMMC isn't what the Ubuntu installer expects which causes some issues or your device is trying to boot in UEFI mode and just can find any EFI boot image (or a mix of both), in this case you should install Ubuntu in UEFI mode if possible.

Comment: The issue here is in fact (2) Legacy Support / Legacy First.  eMMC booting only works in UEFI mode on Lenovo N22.

Answer (score 0):

your installation disk doesn't work. That's all. Try manually once. Press Do something else, delete the partitions, create new ones.

```
Option 1:
1st partition Format EXT4 path /
2nd partition Swap
```

or

```
Option 2:
1st partition Format EXT4 path / (at least 40.000mB)
2: Format EXT4 path /Boot (at least 500mB)
3: Format EXT4 path /Home (full size)
4: Format EXT4 path /tmp (at least 4000mb)
```

If manually installing it doesn't work either, make another usb disk using unetbootin which works 100%. 
You can boot into this live sessing , download ubuntu , 
in a terminal :

```
sudo apt install unetbootin
```

and use it to create a new bootable live session.

Comment: if you need anything , ask me here to check it , edit and add it for you.